# If I change only "A" record in DNS records will it affect to the other records(MX, TXT, etc.)?

Tags: domain-name-system, email, email-server, domain, hosting

I want to change the "A" record in my GoDaddy account to point BlueHost IP address. I have emails in my GoDaddy account, and I don't want to loose them, only need to point the GoDaddy domain to BlueHost hosting. Will this affect to the Emails in my GoDaddy account? I need the Emails work as before, and I can't loose any Email(inbox etc.).
My MX records points to google mail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `MX` always points [(RFC 1035, 3.3.9](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035#section-3.3.9)) to **a** hostname rather than an IP address. Then, according to [RFC 2181, 10.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2181#section-10.3), that hostname should have an `A` record instead of `CNAME`. So

- if `MX` points to **self**, *which is also the fallback if there is no `MX` defined*, changing `A` affects.
- if `MX` points to **anywhere else**, *which is the whole point why `MX` records were invented in the first place*, then changing the `A` record doesn't affect.

Also, `TXT` and other additional `RR`s aren´t affected by changing `A`. But if you'd also like to add `CNAME` to the domain root, then everything gets ruined ([RFC 1034, 3.6.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1034#section-3.6.2)). *Forget I even mentioned it.*

Comment: There are 14 @CNAME records also in DNS zone. With this names: "calendar", "drive", "e", "email", "ftp", "imap", "mail", "mobilemail", "pda", "pop", "smpt", "webmail", "www", "_domainconnect"

Will the "A" affect these records, or vice versa..?

Comment: The `CNAME`s are aliases. If the `CNAME` records are pointing to the changed root record e.g.  `imap.example.com. IN CNAME example.com.`, it will. If they are pointing to somewhere else, e.g. `imap IN CNAME imap.secureserver.net.`, then not.

Comment: Specifically `imap` is pointing to `imap.secureserver.net`, but e.g. `drive` `mail`, `calendar` are pointing to`ghs.googlehosted.com`. `mobilemail`, `pda` to `mobilemail-v01.prod.mesa1.secureserver.net`. `_domainconnect` points to `_domainconnect.gd.domaincontrol.com`, and `www` to `@`.

is it ok? will there be any issues with email?

Comment: While it is good that you want to be certain about this, this could have already been **deducted** from the answer and the previous comment. Only `www` and `@` will be affected as `@ IN A` is changed and you have `www IN CNAME @`. Therefore, there shouldn't be any issues with your email. (However, I'd advice using separate `www A` instead of `www CNAME` as now you also have `www CNAME @ MX mail.example.com.` etc.) You should try to learn to _understand_ how DNS works instead of concentrating on the details in this particular case. I hope this have helped you in starting that journey.

Comment: Thank you very much, you gave me very cognitive response and comments.

Answer (score 1):

That depends. Does the MX point to the hostname? Then it will be affected. Does it point to the IP? Then it will continue to work.

Comment: The MX points to Google Mail. here is one of the MX records: alt1.aspmx.l.google.com (Priority: 20)

Comment: Then it will not be affected.

Comment: so the emails will work as they working now, and no inbox will lost from Godaddy email accounts, am I right?

Comment: Yes. The MX record is not affected by the A record, as long as it doesn't point to the A record.

Answer (score 0):

No it wont affect any of other records, jus change A and restart DNS

Comment: The MX Records are pointing to Google Mail. here is one of the records: alt1.aspmx.l.google.com (Priority: 20)